# Getting Catalogsearch result in observer

Tags: event-observer, catalogsearch

I would like to get the product(Id)'s on a searchresult page in an observer which runs after the initial page render. But I can't seem to get it.
The results are fetched by: `\Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List::_getProductCollection`

But I don't know how to get that in an observer.
Does anybody know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current loaded product collection on category and searchresult pages can be accessed via

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getProductCollection();
```

or, optionally

```
Mage::registry('current_layer')->getProductCollection();
```

[EDIT] Preferred to use the `registry`.

That will return the appropriate model depending on the page you're on. `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer` for catalog and `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer` for search

(Thanks for @janw for clearing that up)

Comment: Hi @sander, thanks for the quick reply. It doesn't work entirely. If I do `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getProductCollection()->getAllIds()` It appears to return all id's almost all available products on the store.

Comment: What event are you using?

Comment: No wait, the `Mage::registry('current_layer')->getProductCollection()->getAllIds()` does work. Both return different models. `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer` vs `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer`

Comment: ah right. makes sense :) so it works?

Comment: Yes it works. What also works is: `Mage::getSingleton('catalogsearch/layer')` If you could update your answer I'll accept

Comment: Updated it and gave credits where due